# RadioButton retornando somente status selecionado

Tags: c#

Segue o código:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlCpfCnpjAvalista" CssClass="cPFCNPJRadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="false">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="CPF" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="CNPJ" Value="2" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Qualquer escolha que eu faço, ele só me trás o `value = 1`. Estes `selected = true`, são minhas tentativas.

```
int teste = int.Parse(rdlCpfCnpjAvalista.SelectedValue);
```

Teste é sempre igual a 1.

Comment: para que tens `Selected="True"`? Ele assim vai buscar o valor do primeiro selecionado, nesse caso, o valor 1

Comment: Mas se deixo sem nada está acontecendo a mesma coisa. Esse selected, como eu disse, já são os testes que eu venho fazendo.

Comment: Acabei de testar, funcionou normal, onde você está colocando esse evento para capturar o valor?

Comment: No Click do botão.

Comment: Testei aqui: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ME3B.png

Comment: Comigo não está funcionando. Só vem Value = 1

Comment: Resolvi. A questão e eu não sei porque, quando eu postei aqui, as caixas se inverteram. É só vê como estão os nomes. deveria ser esse rdlCPFCNPJAvalista e o colega deixou assim: rdlCpfCnpjAvalista

Answer (score 1):

conforme informado pelo @Laerte, realizei o teste abaixo e funcionou perfeitamente.

Aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlCpfCnpjAvalista" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Text="CPF" Value="1" />                
            <asp:ListItem Text="CNPJ" Value="2" />
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEnviar" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="btnEnviar_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

C#

```
protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Verificando se algum valor foi selecionado.
    if (this.rdlCpfCnpjAvalista.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    // Recuperando valor selecionado.
    var valor = this.rdlCpfCnpjAvalista.SelectedValue;
}
```